# Is just continuity enough to prove this?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Sorry if  that´s an idiot question. Let $f: D \longrightarrow \Omega$, such that $D$ is the unitary open disc centered at the origin and $\Omega = \{z \in \mathbb{C}; \mathscr{Re}(z) \geq 0 \}$. If $f$ is analytic in $D$, then I know that $\mathscr{Re}(z) > 0$ holds for all $z \in D$. However it looks like that just the fact of $f$ being continuous is enough for $\mathscr{Re}(z) > 0$ holds, since it looks like that $f(\partial D) \subset i\mathbb{R}$ when one extends $f$ to its limit in the boundary of $D$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: $f(z)=0$ is analytic, and contradicts your claim. Anyway, for non-constant $f$, you can take $f(x+iy)=iy$ as a counterexample.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo It seems very weird. I had this question in a test last week, maybe I´m missing some additional hypothesis.

Comment: Yes, you are missing some additional hypothesis. That $f$ is not constant, for example. The point is that non-constant holomorphic functions are open mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the comments as an answer: First of all, you are missing the assumption that $f$ is non-constant in the case that $f$ is analytic. Without it, $f(z)=0$ is a counterexample. With it, we have that $f$ is an [open map](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/124846/462) and so, its image cannot intersect the boundary of $\Omega$.

Second, to answer your question: No, continuity is not enough. A simple source of examples is obtained by letting $g:(0,1)\to(0,1)$ be continuous, and setting $f(z)=ig(y)$ (or $f(z)=ig(x)$, of course) where $z=x+iy$, with $x,y$ real. For example, $f$ could be the projection onto the $y$ axis. The point is that projections are continuous, so $f$ defined as above is continuous as well, and maps to the boundary of $\Omega$.